# Multithreading strangeness

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf, task-parallel-library

I'm developing a WCF client/server app and the client calls the server asynchronously by wrapping the call in `Task.Factory.StartNew` and using a continuation to call a user-supplied delegate on return from the WCF call. The server operation performs (amongst other things) some serial I/O before returning a response to the client. The service also utilises a BlockingCollection to enqueue these requests, ensuring that they are executed one at a time to avoid serial port contention. As it stands, the app runs perfectly fine, even when the client fires a load of requests to the server in quick succession.

Now, the app can also be configured to run in a "direct" mode, where the client directly references the server-side assemblies (for performance reasons, if client and server are on the same PC). In this scenario the client uses an instance of the service class (rather than a proxy created by ChannelFactory) and calls its operation method directly, using the same asynchronous `Task.Factory.StartNew` helper.

In this "direct" mode I'm finding that the server-side execution seems to run slowly (it misses serial port data), as though it is being interrupted in some way. I can "fix" it by changing the client-side task to use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`. Unfortunately this then breaks the app when in "WCF mode", which seems to suffer the same slowness issues.

Now, I could simply include the TaskCreationOptions (or not) depending on which "mode" the app is using, but I would like to understand why this is happening in the first place. Any ideas?

**Edit**:
I notice the problem during app startup when the client sends a dozen requests to the server one after the other, in a `for` loop. After this the client polls the server every half a second - this isn't affected by the problem, nor are the other couple of thread timers that run both client- and server-side (one of which fires every 65ms!). I came across an article stating that the threadpool will create new threads until the minimum number of threads is reached, after which it limits the number of threads being created to one per 500 milliseconds. This matches the symptoms of my problem as I'm seeing the slowness hit approx every half a second.
I'm going to refactor my client-side code to avoid hitting the server so many times in quick succession, which is a shame. I really wanted to fire off all these requests one after the other, then handle the results in the callback delegates once they had been processed by the server. But with this threadpool "feature" it seems that I can't do this.

Comment: First wild speculation that comes to mind is that that proxy class on the direct side is doing some behind the scenes stuff - as yet unknown - that the direct-instance version isn't. That's where I'd start looking, at least...

Comment: Could you be sharing an instance of some object between your client / server? In WCF mode, you wont be sharing the instance, in direct mode, you could be, and you might have some issue with this?

Comment: @jasper the link is made through a "facade" project - the client references this but no server-side assemblies directly.

Comment: Your update also explains why LongRunning resolves it, as that no longer uses the threadpool

Answer (score 1):

If switching to LongRunning resolves it, that implies that when LongRunning is NOT set, that the task framework is choosing to either use the thread pool, or possibly not even use a seperate thread at all.

Comment: It's odd because the service operation simply enqueues the request to a BlockingCollection and returns very quickly. Puzzling why I would have to specify LongRunning to get it to work. The server-side employs a number of background threads/tasks, so perhaps the client-side async task wrapper stuff is interfering in some way.

Comment: @Andrew I'm as interested as you are to see what the ultimate source of the problem is, but if the actual service operation does complete so quickly, does the client *have* to launch it using a Task? What happens if the client just executes it directly on its current thread?

Comment: @shambulator everything work fine if I just call the operation synchronously. I've probably been so wrapped up in trying to solve the issue using the existing async code that I hadn't thought of this as a solution. I guess the only issue would be if the service is extended in the future to include operations that aren't so short-lived. Perhaps this is one of those "I'll cross that bridge when I come to it" things...

Comment: @shambulator FYI see my edit above for more info on the problem and a possible cause.

Answer (score 0):

You could run some performance tools or attach timers to find out where the bottlenecks are. Alternatively use the WCF mode over a named pipe. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx)